# Getting junk on screen when saving cropped image

Tags: php, gd

My code is working and saving the cropped image, however, I need it to only show what's in the echo.

Right now it shows only the image on the screen if I keep the header line and it does not show what's in the echo.

If I remove the header line, it shows a lot of junk on the screen and then shows the echo.

How can I not show the junk or just the image and make is show what's in the echo?

Here is my code...

```
$src = 'images/'.$imagename;

$w=250;
$h=300;    
$x=$_POST['x'];    
$y=$_POST['y'];  
$png_quality = 0;

// if I remove this header I get junk and nothing from the echo below
header('Content-type: image/png');  

$image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
if (!$src)
exit("not a valid image");
$crop = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
$new = imagecopy ($crop, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h);
imagepng($crop);

imagepng($crop,$src,$png_quality))

echo<<<END
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title> New Image </title>
</head>

<body>
Here is your image:<br /><br />
<img src="images/$imagename">
</body>
</html>
END;
```

Comment: don't have the code that generates the image in the same page that renders any html

Comment: Thing jumping out is syntax error: `imagepng($crop,$src,$png_quality))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up your code a bit. Looks like you are both saving the cropped png and outputting it to the browser with `imagepng($crop);`.  Why?

> imagepng — Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file

Looking at the whole of it I assume you want to crop and update the file on disk, then render that updated file, by using it as the `src` of your `img` attribute.

That header *only* makes sense if you are trying to output the image directly.

```
<?php
  $src = 'images/' . $imagename;

  $w = 250;
  $h = 300;    
  $x = $_POST['x'];    
  $y = $_POST['y'];  
  $png_quality = 0;

  // if I remove this header I get junk and nothing from the echo below
  //header('Content-type: image/png');  

  $image = imagecreatefrompng($src);

  if (!is_resource($image)) exit("not a valid image");

  $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
  $new = imagecopy($crop, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h);
  //imagepng($crop); Is this desired?
  imagepng($crop, $src, $png_quality);  
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title> New Image </title>
</head>    
<body>
  Here is your image:<br /><br />
  <img src="images/<?=$imagename?>">
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, assuming code shared was accurate you should have been getting an error.  Make sure you have error reporting on and are checking logs.  My guess it you rendered the image to browser (where header might help) and then had the script error before even hitting your HTML.

Comment: I only want to upload the image (other part of code), let member crop it, then save the image. Then I want the screen to show what's in the echo, or even better would be to use a `header( 'Location: https://example.com?msg=saved' );
exit;` that way it does not have to output the image at all, just save it and go back to the members page. I would need to update the database first to store the image name before it goes back to the members area.

Comment: Hi Randy, think my answer will help.  Good luck!

Comment: @ficuscar thank you so much. taking out the `imagpng($crop)` worked. I did not know that was showing the image lol. It's all working perfect now.